# Magento 2: Get Product Stock status details in Rest API

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, magento2.3.0, stock-status

Need to get Product `Stock Status` in products details using Rest API.

> Method: GET
>
> Using API URL: http://testwebsite/rest/en/V1/products/sku

Above api returns products details but need also products stock status.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

`Magento ver. 2.3.0`

API Response :

```
{
    "id": 1075,
    "sku": "ACREATSGRACJ5050",
    "name": "Brow Set",
    "attribute_set_id": 14,
    "price": 10.5,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2019-04-06 08:39:24",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-28 06:10:01",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "7"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "77"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "78"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "83"
            }
        ]
    },
    "product_links": [],
    "options": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "brow-set"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "rma_allowed",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "acce_brand",
            "value": "208"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "options_container",
            "value": "container2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "acce_type",
            "value": "223"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "acce_item",
            "value": "209"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "supplier_sku",
            "value": "RT-1468"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "in_html_sitemap",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "retail_price",
            "value": "10.5000"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "use_in_crosslinking",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "in_xml_sitemap",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "7",
                "77",
                "78",
                "83"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "country_of_manufacture",
            "value": "US"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "color",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "upc_ean",
            "value": "79625014686"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "as_featured",
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to get product qty?

Comment: No. Nee to get stock_status like "is_in_stock": true

Comment: You can see in my response. It will perfect working as you want.

Comment: @RohanHapani I need to get stock status with in products details.

Comment: Can you please check chat room?

Comment: Can we get all the product lists and details with their stock status?@RohanHapani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get product stock status from here :

> /V1/stockItems/:productSku

API Response :

```
{
    "item_id": 1,
    "product_id": 1,
    "stock_id": 1,
    "qty": 100,
    "is_in_stock": true,
    "is_qty_decimal": false,
    "show_default_notification_message": false,
    "use_config_min_qty": true,
    "min_qty": 0,
    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
    "min_sale_qty": 1,
    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
    "use_config_backorders": true,
    "backorders": 0,
    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
    "qty_increments": 0,
    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
    "enable_qty_increments": false,
    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
    "manage_stock": true,
    "low_stock_date": null,
    "is_decimal_divided": false,
    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
}
```

---

**UPDATE :**

Get with product details

> /V1/products/:productSku

API Response :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "24-MB01",
    "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
    "attribute_set_id": 15,
    "price": 34,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2019-07-30 10:50:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-30 10:50:45",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "3"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "item_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 100,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        }
    },
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG086",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG083-blue",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UG01",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG085_Group",
            "linked_product_type": "grouped",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB05",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB06",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB04",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB07",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 8
        }
    ],
    "options": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "Image",
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"
            ],
            "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "joust-duffle-bag"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more details, you can see here

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html#cataloginventory

Comment: Thanks @RohanHapani but I would like to add stock status in products details.

http://testwebsite/rest/en/V1/products/sku

Comment: Yes. It's also display in V1/products/sku . You can see in extension_attributes['stock_item'] array element.

Comment: At where you want to get value?

Comment: @KirtiNariya Check my updated answer. You can see is_in_stock inside extension_attributes['stock_item'] in response with product details

Comment: I am trying same V1/products/24-MB01
But can't get in repsonse "stock_item"

Comment: Can you please post your response and magento version?

Comment: Could you please Let me know where I am wrong. For stock item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97971/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-kirti-nariya).

Comment: the attribute stock_item was deprecated on the last versions, there are workarounds but not clear to explain how to apply it. Is there any clear full steps to return stock status within the product details API ?