# Magento 2: Get Product stock quantity details in Rest API

Tags: rest-api, search, magento-2.2.5

Need to get Product stock quantity in products details using Rest API.

Method: GET

Using API URL: [http://127.0.0.1/jaipurart/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25Wood%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like](http://127.0.0.1/jaipurart/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=name&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%25Wood%25&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=like)

Above api returns products details but need also products stock quantity and status.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: Get Product Stock status details in Rest API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286766/magento-2-get-product-stock-status-details-in-rest-api)

Comment: hi @Gagan I have the same issue. Have you managed to get the qty in the products details?

Answer (score 2):

You check this link may be useful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/286769/85907

Get with product details :-

**API Response:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "24-MB01",
    "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
    "attribute_set_id": 15,
    "price": 34,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2019-07-30 10:50:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-30 10:50:45",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "3"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "item_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 100,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        }
    },
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG086",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG083-blue",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UG01",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG085_Group",
            "linked_product_type": "grouped",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB05",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB06",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB04",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB07",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 8
        }
    ],
    "options": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "Image",
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"
            ],
            "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "joust-duffle-bag"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I require product quantity in product search API not according to sku code. Thanks !